# condition of for-loop only takes effect after hitting breakpoint

Tags: c++, gdb

I'm trying to solve a problem from hackerrank.

At the moment my code is bad and wrong, but that's not the point of this question.
The problem is the `for` loop, whose condition doesn't always seem to work.
Here's the code:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

// Integer power.
long ipow(int x, int y)
{
    assert(x > 0);
    assert(y >= 0);

    long res = 1;
    while (y--)
        res *= x;
    return res;
}

std::set<int> compute_distinct_sequence_numbers(int n, int s, int p, int q)
{
    static_assert(sizeof(long) > 4, "long is assumed to be larger 4 bytes");

    set<int> distinct_numbers;
    const long max1 = ipow(2, 31);  // maximum plus 1

    // Compute first number of sequence.
    int prev = s % max1;
    distinct_numbers.emplace(prev);

    // Compute subsequent elements of sequence and put them in set.
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        prev = (prev * p + q) % max1;
        distinct_numbers.emplace(prev);
    }

    return distinct_numbers;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Read numbers.
    int n, s, p, q;
    if (!(cin >> n >> s >> p >> q))
        throw std::runtime_error("error on input");;

    // Compute set containing distinct number of sequence.
    std::set<int> distinct_numbers = compute_distinct_sequence_numbers(n, s, p, q);

    // Print number of distinct numbers in sequence.
    cout << distinct_numbers.size() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If I run the program with the input "10000000 658061970 695098531 1430548937", it takes a very long time to complete (almost 20 seconds).

The main problem I have with this, is that the loop doesn't exit when `i` reaches `n`.
When I stop the program in GDB, the program is stuck in the loop and `i` may have a value larger than `n`.

The following GDB session demonstrates this:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/janosch/programming/hackerrank/cpp/main 
10000000 658061970 695098531 1430548937

Breakpoint 1, compute_distinct_sequence_numbers (n=10000000, s=658061970, p=695098531, q=1430548937) at main.cpp:32
32              prev = (prev * p + q) % max1;
(gdb) print i
$7 = 10000000
(gdb) info breakpoints 
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address            What
1       breakpoint     keep y   0x00000000004010c0 in compute_distinct_sequence_numbers(int, int, int, int) at main.cpp:32
        stop only if i = n
        breakpoint already hit 1 time
(gdb) n
33              distinct_numbers.emplace(prev);
(gdb) 
31          for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
(gdb) 
36          return distinct_numbers;
(gdb) 
37      }
```

I've set a conditional breakpoint (`i == n`) on the line 
`prev = (prev * p + q) % max1;`.
Normally it should not be possible to hit this breakpoint, since the loop should exit before hitting `n`.
Even if I use a much higher value for the conditional breakpoint (like `i == 2*n`), the breakpoint is hit.

Once I hit the breakpoint, the program exits the loop immediately. This is true for single-stepping (GDB command `n`) and continuing (GDB command `c`).

Here is my super simple Makefile:

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -Wall -std=c++14 -c -g
LDFLAGS = 

all:    main

main:   main.o
        $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) main.o -o main

main.o: main.cpp
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.cpp
```

The program is running on Ubuntu 16.04.

What am I doing wrong?
How can the program behave differently when running in GDB?
This seems to be embarrassingly simple.

Comment: Integer overflow maybe? Try changing all your `int` types to `long` types (you have an assert that 'long` > 4 bytes but then never use `long`?

Comment: `info breakpoints`  says `stop only if i = n`. Was that a typo? I'd expect it to be `stop only if i == n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Once I hit the breakpoint, the program exits the loop immediately.

This is an instance of [PEBKAC](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/p/pebkac.htm). As Mark Plotnick noticed, your breakpoint condition is not just a condition, but a condition *and* an assignment.

Every time the condition is evaluated, `i` is assigned the value `n`, and then the result is evaluated against 0.

This means that under debugger, with this particular "conditional" breakpoint in place, your loop executes exactly once.

Now, when I *don't* attach GDB at all, I observe:

```
$ g++ -g t.cc -O0 &&  echo "10000000 658061970 695098531 1430548937" | time ./a.out
10000000
18.15user 0.20system 0:18.36elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 472032maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+117322minor)pagefaults 0swaps

$ g++ -g t.cc -O2 &&  echo "10000000 658061970 695098531 1430548937" | time ./a.out
10000000
12.09user 0.14system 0:12.27elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 472028maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+117322minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

from which we can conclude that the program is slow because it executes 10 million iterations, and not because the `for` loop is somehow broken.

Using `perf record` and `perf report`, we can see *where* all this time is spent:

```
# Samples: 50K of event 'cycles:uppp'
# Event count (approx.): 50290745010
#
# Overhead  Command  Shared Object        Symbol                                                                                                         
# ........  .......  ...................  ...............................................................................................................
#
    79.02%  a.out    a.out                [.] std::_Rb_tree<int, int, std::_Identity<int>, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int> >::_M_emplace_unique<int&>
     8.75%  a.out    a.out                [.] std::_Rb_tree<int, int, std::_Identity<int>, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int> >::_M_erase
     5.82%  a.out    libstdc++.so.6.0.25  [.] std::_Rb_tree_insert_and_rebalance
     0.93%  a.out    libstdc++.so.6.0.25  [.] 0x00000000000a9440
     0.89%  a.out    libc-2.28.so         [.] _int_malloc
     0.86%  a.out    libc-2.28.so         [.] cfree@GLIBC_2.2.5
     0.81%  a.out    a.out                [.] compute_distinct_sequence_numbers
     0.78%  a.out    libc-2.28.so         [.] _int_free
```